# Correct spatial selection method

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, select-by-location

I have layer containing a area that will be flooded if the water level rises 6 meters. I also have a layer containing roads for the whole area. I want to export all the roads that will be under water in case of a 6 meter water level rise.

What I have tried is to use *Select by location* with roads as target layer and the 6meter flooding layer as source layer. I have used ALL the spatial selection methods but none of them selects only roads that inside the flooding zone. I guess it's because it selects the roads, but the roads is composed by different line segments.

How should I do to select the roads correctly?

I am using ArcMap 10.2.2 with all the extensions.

Comment: There is an [edit] button beneath your question that you should use to revise it with any details like this that help to make what you are asking clearer.

Comment: You want to select the complete road that is being flooded or only that part of the road which falls in the 6m flooding zone?

Comment: Only the part of the road which falls in the 6m flooding zone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To export just the roads that will be underwater, simply clip your roads by the flood polygon layer.  The result is all roads that will be flooded and will exclude portions of flooded roads where they emerge above the water.

If you ONLY want to select roads that will be underwater, you will need to intersect the roads with the polygons to cut the roads at the 'flood' line and then select by location.

Comment: "If you ONLY want to select roads that will be underwater, you will need to intersect the roads with the polygons to cut the roads at the 'flood' line and then select by location."

Sorry but how do I do this? Not asking for a spoonfeeding, but what tool?